# How do I make my Factory's Header not dependent on the templated objects it creates?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, dependencies, factory

I have an abstract base class like so:

```
class AbstractBaseClass
{};
```

a templated concrete class that derives from it:

```
template<class T>
class ConcreteClass : public AbstractBaseClass
{
public:
   ConcreteClass(T input) : data(input) {}
private:
    T data;
};
```

AndI have a factory class that creates AbstractBaseClasses

```
class MyFactory
{
public:
   boost::shared_ptr<AbstractBaseClass> CreateBlah();
   boost::shared_ptr<AbstractBaseClass> CreateFoo();

   template<class T>
   boost::shared_ptr<AbstractBaseClass> Create(T input)
   {
      return boost::shared_ptr<AbstractBaseClass>(new ConcreteClass<T>(input));
   }
};
```

The problem with this, is that now EVERYTHING that uses MyFactory has to include the entire implementation to ConcreteClass. Ideally, I want nothing but MyFactory to know about ConcreteClass.

Is there any way to architect this to achieve this goal? (Besides manually making a new Create function in MyFactory for every type I want instead of templating it).

Comment: `ConcreteClass` is visible, but you could make it `private` to reduce its accessibility. Is it worth the trouble to completely hide it from users ?

Comment: Im in a very very large codebase, where its important for us to think about reducing header dependencies and compile times and such, so thats why I am bothering with thinking about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize I am answering this five years later.  Maybe the language has grown a tad since then.  I'd like to offer something that seems right, if I understand the question properly, if for no other point than to help others who might find this question and wonder what they could do.

---

*factory.hpp*

```
#include "base.hpp"

namespace tvr
{
    namespace test
    {
        class factory
        {
        public:
            typedef base::ptr Ptr;

            enum eSpecial
            {
                eDerived
            };

            template<typename Type>
            Ptr create()
            {
                Ptr result;
                result.reset(new Type());
                return result;
            }

            template<typename Type, typename DataType>
            Ptr create(const DataType& data)
            {
                Ptr result;
                result.reset(new Type(data));
                return result;
            }

            template<typename Type, typename DataType>
            Ptr create(const DataType& data, eSpecial tag)
            {
                Ptr result;
                result.reset(new Type());
                static_cast<Type*>(result.get())->set_item(data);
                return result;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

*base.hpp*

```
#include <memory>

namespace tvr
{
    namespace test
    {
        class base
        {
        public:
            typedef std::shared_ptr<base> ptr;

        public:
            base() {}
            virtual ~base() {}
            virtual void do_something() = 0;
        };
    }
}
```

---

*some_class.hpp*

```
#include <ostream>

namespace tvr
{
    namespace test
    {
        struct some_class
        {
        };
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const tvr::test::some_class& item)
{
    out << "This is just some class.";
    return out;
}
```

---

*template_derived.hpp*

```
#include <iostream>

#include "base.hpp"

namespace tvr
{
    namespace test
    {
        template<typename Type>
        class template_derived : public base
        {
        public:
            template_derived(){}
            virtual ~template_derived(){}
            virtual void do_something()
            {
                std::cout << "Doing something, like printing _item as \"" << _item << "\"." << std::endl;
            }

            void set_item(const Type data)
            {
                _item = data;
            }
        private:
            Type _item;
        };
    }
}
```

---

*and, finally, main.cpp*

```
#include <vector>

#include "base.hpp"
#include "factory.hpp"

namespace tvr
{
    namespace test
    {
        typedef std::vector<tvr::test::base::ptr> ptr_collection;

        struct iterate_collection
        {
            void operator()(const ptr_collection& col)
            {
                for (ptr_collection::const_iterator iter = col.begin();
                    iter != col.end();
                    ++iter)
                {
                    iter->get()->do_something();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

#include "template_derived.hpp"
#include "some_class.hpp"

namespace tvr
{
    namespace test
    {
        inline int test()
        {
            ptr_collection items;

            tvr::test::factory Factory;

            typedef template_derived<unsigned int> UIntConcrete;
            typedef template_derived<double> DoubleConcrete;
            typedef template_derived<std::string> StringConcrete;
            typedef template_derived<some_class> SomeClassConcrete;

            items.push_back(Factory.create<SomeClassConcrete>(some_class(), tvr::test::factory::eDerived));
            for (unsigned int i = 5; i < 7; ++i)
            {
                items.push_back(Factory.create<UIntConcrete>(i, tvr::test::factory::eDerived));
            }
            items.push_back(Factory.create<DoubleConcrete>(4.5, tvr::test::factory::eDerived));
            items.push_back(Factory.create<StringConcrete>(std::string("Hi there!"), tvr::test::factory::eDerived));

            iterate_collection DoThem;
            DoThem(items);

            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    tvr::test::test();
}
```

---

*output*

```
Doing something, like printing _item as "This is just some class.".
Doing something, like printing _item as "5".
Doing something, like printing _item as "6". 
Doing something, like printing _item as "4.5".
Doing something, like printing _item as "Hi there!".
```

---

This uses a combination of templates, function overloading, and tagging through enums to help create a flexible factory class that doesn't require knowing much about the individual classes it instantiates, to include templated concrete classes as the OP asked about.

The 'eDerived' tag (in the form of an enum) tells the compiler to use the version of the factory's create function that takes a class like the template_derived class, which has a function that allows me to assign data to one of its members.  As you can tell from the way I ordered the headers in main.cpp, the factory doesn't know anything about template_derived.  Neither does the function calling the base class's virtual function (do_something).  I think this is what the OP wanted, but without having to add a various create functions within every class that this factory might generate.

I also showed how one doesn't have to explicitly create functions for each class the factory should create.  The factory's overloaded create functions can create anything derived from the base class that matches the appropriate signature.

I didn't do an extensive performance analysis on this code, but I did enough to see that the majority of the work happens in the streaming operator.  This compiles in about 1 second on my 3.30Ghz quad core machine.  You might need to experiment with more robust code to see how badly it might bog down the compiler, if much at all.

I've tested this code in VC++ 2015, although it probably works in other compilers pretty easily.  If you want to copy this, you'll need to add your own guard headers.  In any event, I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 5):

you'll need to put the factory implementation into the implementation file (which you mentioned you'd like to avoid, but it is the lesser evil unless the interfaces are small, and/or your projects are small).

of course, there are a few other ways you could approach this, such as putting the implementation into base classes, and making derived bases factories, or using some other really weird template syntax to reduce instantiations in dependent translations. this really comes down to convenience and scale for your project. if you are working on one or more large projects, then full abstraction wrt instantiation will serve your needs best in the long run (assuming you need dynamic polymorphism and memory).

you may also try other approaches (such as overloading) to reduce errors by using type-safety.

the short answer is that you'll really need to abstract the interfaces/instantiation into one or multiple implementation files to remove header dependencies - very common idiom, and many ways to tackle it. you can over course further divide and use polymorphism for your factories as well.

you may also use template forward declarations to minimize the sets to the compilation unit. provided:

```
/** in MyIntermediateFactory.hpp */
class MyIntermediateFactory {
public:
    static template<class T> boost::shared_ptr<T> Create(float);
};

/** in Concrete.hpp */
template<Concrete>
boost::shared_ptr<T> MyIntermediateFactory::Create<Concrete>(float arg) {
    /* … */
}
```

using this you can select portions of programs/interfaces which you need in the library, then wrap it all up in a real Factory (for the build at hand). the linker/instantiation should fail along the way if you actually attempt to request a creation which is not visible.

there a lot of options, really - you need to figure out how big your scale is in order to determine what to abstract (or not). instantiation requires interface, to remove header dependencies, you'll have to abstract the instantiation someplace.

Answer (score 2):

My approach to the same problem in the past was the creation of a set of concrete factories (one per type) that get registered in the global factory (for illustration purposes, indexing by object name):

```
class AbstractBaseClass;
class ConcreteFactory
{
public:
   AbstractBaseClass * create();
};
class AbstractFactory 
{
public:
   void registerFactory( std::string const & name, std::shared_ptr<ConcreteFactory> const & f )
   {
      factory[ name ] = f; // check for collisions, complain if so ...
   }
   AbstractBaseClass * create( std::string const & name )
   {
      return factory[name]->create(); // check for existence before dereferencing...
   }
private:
   std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<ConcreteFactory> > factory;
};
```

I used this in a piece of code that was heavily templated to reduce compilation time. Each concrete factory and the class that it creates need only be in a single translation unit that registers the concrete factory. The rest of the code only need to use the common interface to `AbstractBaseClass`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use explicit template instanciation. Trying to call the factory method with a template parameter not explicit instanciated will give you a linker error. Note the explicit template instanciation in MyFactory.cpp

```
template AbstractBaseClass* MyFactory::Create(int input);
```

**All put together looks like this (I removed shared_ptr for the sake of simplicity):**

Main.cpp:

```
#include "AbstractBaseClass.h"
#include "MyFactory.h"

//we do not need to know nothing about concreteclass (neither MyFactory.h includes it)    

int main()
{
    MyFactory f;
    AbstractBaseClass* ab = f.Create(10);
    ab = f.Create(10.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

MyFactory.h:

```
#include "AbstractBaseClass.h"

class MyFactory
{
public:

   template<class T>
   AbstractBaseClass* Create(T input);
 };
```

MyFactory.cpp:

```
#include "MyFactory.h"
#include "ConcreteClass.h"

template<class T>
AbstractBaseClass* MyFactory::Create(T input) {
    return new ConcreteClass<T>(input);
}

//explicit template instanciation
template AbstractBaseClass* MyFactory::Create(int input);

//you could use as well specialisation for certain types
template<>
AbstractBaseClass* MyFactory::Create(float input) {
    return new ConcreteClass<float>(input);
}
```

AbstractBaseClass.h:

```
class AbstractBaseClass{};
```

ConcreteClass.h:

```
#include "AbstractBaseClass.h"

template<class T>
class ConcreteClass : public AbstractBaseClass
{
public:
   ConcreteClass(T input) : data(input) {}
private:
    T data;
};
```

Comment: interesting, didnt know I could do this.

Comment: unfortunately, there aren't any compilers (except Comeau's one) that can compile MyFactory.h. You simply can't declare a templated function and define it in another file. It is, indeed, in the standard, but nobody supports this feature.

Comment: @grim the code compiles (and works) with gcc-4.4 will check this with visual studio...

Comment: @grim see that: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/atl/tutorials/article.php/c3617 - it states that explicit template instanciation wasn't well supported by Visual Studio 6

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the "PIMPL" idiom. There's a good explanation at [Herb Sutter's GOTW site](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm)

Comment: Im not sure how PImpl would help me here. Since I am dealing with Templates, the implementation is needed at compile time. Since the Factory's create method is templated, it would need to call the PImpl's function from the header file. If I am missing something, could you please be more specific?

Comment: It would reduce the dependency to the interface, but not completely remove it. To get completely free, you'll need to use a registry-type approach, where the Factory doesn't know what it's loading until runtime. This kind of thing is common for plugin architectures, where the Factory reads a registry to find out how to create something. It's a bit hairier, but pretty cool when you get it working.

Comment: you would lose compiler static check if your implementation depends on something not written in source code.

Comment: @YeenFei: Not completely - plugin architectures in C++ have both the plugin and plugged-into depend on a common header, though they're not compiled together. While this does leave room for human error, as long as both compilations use the same file, you have static compile-time checking of the code. Your registration system, if dependent on configuration files, could have run-time only errors, but all of your code is still checked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done because ConcreteClass is a template, that means you need the complete implementation available at compile time. Same reason why you can't precompile templates and have to write them all in header files instead.

Comment: you can - via explicit template instanciation